# Can I ask a question in the form of a video?

Tags: discussion, support

Can I ask a question in the form of a video? For example, record a video, put it on YouTube, and link it?

This will help me explain my problem better so that everyone can see what I mean. Can you do that?

Comment: Please research before considering asking. [ask] [help]

Comment: Apart from anything else, it would be misused immediate. Videos of sundry spam, threats and illegal porn would be posted within an hour of allowing such a service:(

Comment: @MartinJames I mean there is nothing stopping people from doing that right now, links to videosites are not blocked.

Comment: @Gimby yes, and I'm sure that misuse already happens and that the CM/mods already delete such garbage.  SO should specifically refuse any measure that might be interpreted as adding any kind of legitimacy to such abuse.

Comment: ...you know how these 'people' work, right?  They would post an innocent-looking question with a link to illegal porn and, simultaneously, link the question on Twotter/Facepalm with the title 'LOOK! The toxic, hostile SO are now supporting kiddie porn!  Shut them down!' :(

Comment: If you want to demonstrate a GUI, short GIFs are allowed and embeddable, so you can show responses on button clicks, or what you're doing exactly to get an error.

Comment: What if my question is described with attached files? But for me to be better understood and in addition to describing the problem and attaching files, I will record and post a short video on YouTube recorded in BANDICAM from my desktop showing my problem and add a link to it?

Comment: @wojbuk - There isn’t a mechanism to attach files.  Please write your questions in the appropriate written language for the community.  A question that only includes a video isn’t an appropriate question and will be deleted

Answer (score 18):

In short, no you shouldn't do that. Your question will likely be closed and deleted without an answer if you do.

Your question must be self-contained here. I.e. it should not be necessary to visit external links in order to make sense of or answer it.

Videos are not searchable, they don't work well for screen readers either so other people will find it hard to find your question if it happens to be the same issue that they are stuck on and questions here should not be specific to you, they should be general enough that we might hope to help a number of people with its answers.

On top of that if there's any code in your question we can hardly copy and paste it out of a video and use it as part of an answer.